# Optimizing rc4 encryption

Tags: c++, openssl

I am working on an rc4 encryption implementation for s3fs and I'd like to better optimize my design so I'd like feedback on my encryption/decryption here.

Below is the code which accepts a file descriptor of an open file for a parameter:

```
void crypty(int fd){
    // Initial steps, read the file into a buffer
    ssize_t placeHolder; // Needed to reduce warnings in compilation
    int fileLength = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END); // use of system call to measure offset in accordance to the end of the file, yielding the size
    unsigned char* fileContents; // generate a new c-string pointer
    fileContents = (unsigned char*) calloc(fileLength, sizeof(char)); // assign that pointer to a block of memmory allocated by calloc() that has enough cells for the full file size and the size of each cell is the size of a char or 1byte
    placeHolder = pread(fd, fileContents, fileLength, 0); // read from the file of the file descriptor into the file-contents of size up to the size of fileLength or the length of the file
  // Cast the results into a string for temporary storage
    string plain(reinterpret_cast<char*>(fileContents), fileLength); // strongest cast to the bit level to ensure string is converted fully from c-string ideal for pointers
     int length = plain.size(); // sets length to the length of the string
     unsigned char *buf = (unsigned char*)malloc(length+1); // allocates requested memory of a certain size and then sets the pointer to it to be the pointer I declared prior
     memset(buf, 0, length+1); // fills the memory with blank placeholder, chosen to be 0
     // Grabbing password
     ifstream pass; // opens file stream
     string code; // makes string to grab password
     pass.open("pass.txt"); // opens password file
     if(!pass.good()){
        code = "morganna"; // Fail safe in case s3 doesn't open my file
        pass.close();
     }
     else{
         //Take the passphrase given and turn it into an md5 hash for use in rc4
         getline(pass,code);
         pass.close();
     }
        // Starting open-ssl styled md5 conversion
         char codeConverted[code.length()]; // makes an equivalent length c-string
         strcpy(codeConverted,code.c_str()); // makes an equivalent length copy of the string

         unsigned char encryptedPass[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH]; // generates an array to begin md-5 hashing
         char convertedPass[16]; // makes a c-string to hold the conversion
         MD5((unsigned char*)&codeConverted, strlen(codeConverted), (unsigned char*)&encryptedPass); // conduct hash

         for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
         sprintf(&mdString[i*2], "%02x", (unsigned int)encryptedPass[i]); // takes each digit in hex and converts to ascii equivalence for readability in testing
         }

         for (int i = 0; i < 16;i++){
             convertedPass[i] = encryptedPass[i]; // copy fully converted password into new string
         }
         // Do encryption
         RC4_KEY key;
         RC4_set_key(&key,sizeof(convertedPass), (const unsigned char*)convertedPass);
         RC4(&key, length, (const unsigned char*)plain.c_str(), buf);
         // Write the encryption back to the old file
         string result((char*)buf, length);
         free(buf); // deallocate memory used prior
         // Final result
         const char *outputBuf = result.c_str();
         placeHolder = pwrite(fd, outputBuf, result.length(), 0); // Writes WITHOUT changing the offset from prior
         placeHolder = ftruncate(fd, result.length()); // truncates file
         return; // returns blank because function is void 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the tag C++ is correct. This seems much more like good old C

Comment: @miscco no it's definitely c++, it's a function added to a much larger cpp file. But since the way I designed it needs to manipulate a file by a file descriptor I couldn't find any other way to do it than using some c system calls. I originially tried to use stringstream and fstream but that didn't turn out so hot

Comment: I think there's a memory leak: you're not freeing memory allocated for `fileContents` buffer.